# NTFS compressed folders: is it possible to tweak compression ratio?

Tags: windows, ntfs, compression

As it seems, Windows compresses the NTFS compressed folders with the lowest compression ratio possible. While this maybe good for increasing speed and decreasing CPU load, for the files that are accessed rarely (backup folders) it would be more sensible to have the possibility to increase the compression ratio. Are there some parameters that may be tweaked to achieve this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363849(v=vs.85).aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: They say about "compression format": "Any other value indicates that a file is compressed, using the compression format specified by the compression state value." I didn't find what this "format" means and how it is set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Short answer

No, it's not possible at this time.

## Long answer

Files and folders<sup>1</sup> are compressed and decompressed by passing a `FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION` control code and a [compression state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the `DeviceIoControl` [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) function. The compression state can be one of the following:

```
COMPRESSION_FORMAT_NONE = 0
COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT = 1
COMPRESSION_FORMAT_LZNT1 = 2
```

Any nonzero value means the target item is going to be compressed. From the official documentation:

> The LZNT1 compression algorithm is the only compression algorithm implemented. As a result, the LZNT1 compression algorithm is used as the `DEFAULT` compression method.
>
> <sub>Source: [FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION control code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

The LZNT1 algorithm is designed for speed, and there's no way to set a custom compression level.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Folders aren't actually compressed: their compression attribute only gives a default compression state to new files and subfolders.</sub>

### Additional information

> The NTFS file system volumes support file compression on an individual file basis. The file compression algorithm used by the NTFS file system is Lempel-Ziv compression. This is a *lossless* compression algorithm, which means that no data is lost when compressing and decompressing the file, as opposed to *lossy* compression algorithms such as JPEG, where some data is lost each time data compression and decompression occur.
>
> On the NTFS file system, compression is performed transparently. This means it can be used without requiring changes to existing applications.
>
> If you compress a file that is larger than 30 gigabytes, the compression may not succeed.
>
> <sub>Source: [File Compression and Decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>
>
> The compression algorithms in NTFS are designed to support cluster sizes of up to 4 KB. When the cluster size is greater than 4 KB on an NTFS volume, none of the NTFS compression functions are available.
>
> <sub>Source: [File and Folder Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976802.aspx)</sub>

### Further reading

- [File Compression and Decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [File and Folder Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976802.aspx)
- [Understanding NTFS Compression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression.aspx)
- [LZNT1 Algorithm Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj665697.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

Generally it's not possible, as indicated in [and31415's answer](https://superuser.com/a/775178/241386).

However Microsoft has added some **new NTFS compression options and algorithms** in Windows 10, so now there's a way to change the compression ratio:

```
COMPACT [/C | /U] [/S[:dir]] [/A] [/I] [/F] [/Q] [/EXE[:algorithm]]
        [/CompactOs[:option] [/WinDir:dir]] [filename [...]]
...
  /EXE       Use compression optimized for executable files which are read
             frequently and not modified.  Supported algorithms are:
             XPRESS4K  (fastest) (default)
             XPRESS8K
             XPRESS16K
             LZX       (most compact)
```

The new algorithms are intended for the new [Compact OS feature](https://superuser.com/q/1011288/241386) (as you can see in the `/CompactOs` option above). The idea is to compress *read-only, backup and less frequently accessed system files* with the highest ratio. The recovery partition is removed and the compressed file will then be used for both executing (if it's already the latest version) and recovery purpose

The LZX algorithm is [quite efficient](https://superuser.com/q/907008/241386) at archiving. And despite the option name and description are all about "executable files", the option can be applied to any files

```
E:\test>compact /a

 Listing E:\test\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

  1050909 :   1050909 = 1.0 to 1   sometext.txt

...

E:\test>compact /c /exe:lzx sometext.txt

 Compressing files in E:\test\

sometext.txt          1050909 :    176128 = 6.0 to 1 [OK]

1 files within 1 directories were compressed.
1,050,909 total bytes of data are stored in 176,128 bytes.
The compression ratio is 6.0 to 1.
```

However unlike the old algorithm they don't support *on-the-fly editing*, so writing back to the file uncompresses it.

```
E:\test>echo x >> sometext.txt

E:\test>compact /a

 Listing E:\test\
 New files added to this directory will not be compressed.

  1050913 :   1050913 = 1.0 to 1   sometext.txt
```

---

An important note is that you can't set the folder to [mark new files to be compressed automatically using those new algorithms](https://superuser.com/q/979702/241386), because as stated in the help part of `compact` (emphasis mine)

```
/C         Compresses the specified files.  Directories will be marked
           so that files added afterward will be compressed unless /EXE
           is specified.
/U         Uncompresses the specified files.  Directories will be marked
           so that files added afterward will not be compressed.  If
           /EXE is specified, only files compressed as executables will
           be uncompressed; if this is omitted, only NTFS compressed
           files will be uncompressed.
```

Therefore if you want to use them for back-up files you might have to run a script to compress manually after backing up or periodically after some time

Unfortunately this new in Windows 10, therefore it can't be used in older versions. However [NTFS-3g does support it](https://github.com/ebiggers/ntfs-3g-system-compression/blob/master/README.md), therefore you won't have problem accessing it from Linux. If you don't use Windows 10 you can run a Linux live USB or Windows 10 PE to open those files

Answer (score 1):

You can increase compression ratio by 3rd-party apps. The prime example is ***[zipmagic.co](http://zipmagic.co)***  I've used it on my laptop for a year without any problem. But notice that using NTFS or Zipmagic compression needs SSD hard drive because compression will make your drive totally fragmented and make it useless! If you have SSD drive, so go ahead and enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

It would be possible to compress with maximum compression by directly compressing files and bypassing NTFS compression API but afterwards compressed files will be accessible as LZNT1 decompress works same for any compression strength.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately as of now, the NTFS file system under Windows only supports Xpress4k, 8k, 16k, and LZX, which are several compression methods.

However, if you move the option away from NTFS, such as [WinBtrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs), you may get a better compression ratio and usage experience.

Comment: the question is whether it's possible to "tweak compression ratio" and by changing the compression method like above you already change the compression ratio